# Removing words/numbers from text

Tags: text-processing

I have text and would like to remove last 3 words from every line. How is it possible to do it?

Comment: You're really going to need to be more specific - this question is very vague as it is currently written. Can you at least tag this with the language that you're using? Providing a code sample would be even better.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correction_fluid

Answer (score 4):

To this very specific description, i can suggest the following methods:

1. place your cursor at the end of the first line
2. press backspace until the last 3 words deleted
3. place your cursor at the end of the second line
4. press...
   so on.

Comment: or iterate through every line and define what is a word, then remove the last 3 from every line.

Comment: Or hire someone to do this for you.

Comment: You could also record a macr... forget it.

Comment: @belisarius: Notepad doesn't have those macros ;-)

Comment: @darioo the Emacs picture is awesome!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can:

1. Do split(" ") on your strings and then combine elements without last
2. From the end of every string go to beginning, until you find 3 words. Then substring().

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have your lines of text in a string, let's say it's in PHP, so it's as if you read in a file with

```
$lines = file('somefile.txt');
```

which creates an array of the lines in the file.  If you want to re-output all the lines in that file without the last three words, I recommend:

```
while ($line = array_shift($lines)) { 
  $line = preg_split('/\w+/', $line); 
  array_slice($line, 0, -3);
  echo implode(' ', $line);
}
```

Comment: Please reformat your code for readability. Think in the next generations of programmers in need for this snippet :)